# Should I formally enroll in courses related to my PhD?

Tags: phd, coursework, eu

I have a background in IT/Communications Eng. I also had study gaps. However, I have extensive knowledge and proficiency in computer programming and algorithms. I am doing a 4-years **interdisciplinary** Ph.D. I am working on protein modeling and simulation.

In my research, it is essential to have concepts in protein-geometry, molecular dynamic simulation, and structural bioinformatics. However, I never formally enrolled in those courses. I studied them myself, and that was enough for me. The advantage of self-study was that I never had to worry about my grades, attendance, and so on, which was a productive way for me.

Should I formally enroll in those courses? Would there be any adverse consequence If I don't? I.e., would someone in the future think that *"**This** guy completed the Ph.D. but didn't have any formal education on proteins, etc.? **that** guy is from biology/chemistry/etc. So it is wise for us to choose **that** guy for a PostDoc position...!"*

Comment: @Buffy, *Are you required to take comprehensive/qualifying exams?* --- what do you mean? Plz rephrase.

Comment: In the US, one first takes courses, then a set of exams covering the major field. Only then are you a "candidate" for the doctorate, though your research might have started already. It is a major hurdle in many fields. In math it is 3 or 4 exams, including one or more oral exams possibly. It is really a US concern only, I'll guess. The courses are there mostly to prepare for the exams and the exams are there to assure you have broad knowledge of your field. Then the dissertation verifies depth in some aspect. Breadth + depth.

Comment: @Buffy, *In the US, one first takes courses, then a set of exams covering the major field. The courses are there mostly to prepare for the exams, and the exams are there to ensure you have a broad knowledge of your field.* --- I have to take some courses as part of my Ph.D. However, the courses are selected by me, not a Ph.D. curriculum. There is no defined curriculum for my interdisciplinary Ph.D.

Comment: Yes, UK and Europe in general is quite different.

Comment: What does your advisor think?

Comment: @BryanKrause, *What does your advisor think?* --- That is an excellent question. He prescribed me a minimum number of courses to work on and finish my Ph.D. project.

Comment: @user366312 Have you asked him the question you asked here?

Comment: @BryanKrause, No.

Comment: Why not? Seems good to get advice from an advisor.

Comment: Not necessarily EU related, but one possible consideration is whether these courses could be relevant to some kind of formal qualification later.  At my US institution, for our accreditation there is a rule that in order for someone to teach courses in discipline X, if it is not the field of their graduate degree, then they must have taken 6 graduate courses in X as shown on their transcript.  So conceivably, enrolling in such courses might affect whether you can teach biology or bioinformatics courses someday.  You'd want to look into rules for your part of the world.

Comment: @NateEldredge, You can post your comment as an answer, and I will accept that. This is very important information.

Comment: This question is very dependent on your specific university- what do your head of studies, program coordinator(s), doctoral student representatives and/or more advanced students in your program think? Enrolling formally can result in a lot more non-science workload and wreck your GPA, or it could kill two birds with one stone by teaching you new techniques and fulfilling your credit requirement. But this is not something strangers on the internet can tell you.

Comment: "_there is a rule that in order for someone to teach courses in discipline X, if it is **not** the field of their graduate degree, then they must have taken 6 graduate courses in X as shown on their transcript._" You already have PhD in statistical mechanic, why do you have the recent question for the barriers when you want to teach statistical mechanic? What exactly is your most recent question about ???

Comment: Also, please see the last paragraph of the answer below: "_So, if you can go to those classes for free and you have the time, it wouldn't hurt._" If you really feel there is some kind of barrier, take a couple of classes while you're still a PhD student. (Based on this question, you're a PhD student, aren't you?) Please don't spend so much time on this matter, concentrate on your research. Your worry is un-necessary.

Comment: @Nobody, *You already have PhD in statistical mechanic* --- No, I don't. I am a Ph.D. student.

Comment: @Nobody, *If you really feel there is some kind of barrier, take a couple of classes while you're still a Ph.D. student.* --- I prefer not to do that because it is an unnecessary burden of anxiety regarding my grades.

Comment: @Nobody, *Please don't spend so much time on this matter, concentrate on your research. Your worry is unnecessary.* --- I am surveying. Coz, I am older than most Ph.D. students, I have a family, and I need a job as soon as I finish my Ph.D. I have less time to settle than other Ph.D. degree-holders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry that much.

1. You're doing a PhD in a field and, when you are done, you are an expert in your field (if you feel like one or not) with publications showing your expertise. Publications are important if you apply for a PostDoc or another job.
2. Nobody (academia nor industry) will ask what modules/classes you took at the beginning of your PhD. They will see that you did the PhD and your expertise based on your publications.

I did my PhD in robotics, and we had psychologists and chemists doing robotics research too. I have friends who are computer scientists who did systems biology research (computer models, protein folding, ...). They didn't struggle to find post-docs or jobs afterward in their field.
So, I believe you don't need to worry it.

Having said that, being able to prove that you studied something (a certificate or a grade from a Uni) can only help. If you want to feel more confident when applying for jobs, do some modules/classes. But I don't think it is needed.

Another benefit of doing classes is that you won't miss something. Often, people skip parts of a subject as it seems too academic or irrelevant when they self-study; however, this is the knowledge that is often useful to have.
For instance, in computer science, algorithm analysis (big O or theta notation) is often skipped by people who study themselves, but in practice, it is quite useful. Similar things might exist in your domain. So, if you can go to those classes for free and you have the time, it wouldn't hurt.