# What kind of barriers will he face during the hiring process?

Tags: teaching

Suppose, someone did his bachelor's from the faculty of humanities, master's from the faculty of social science, and then received a Ph.D. in statistical mechanics and did postdocs in the same field.

In other words, he never studied any "course". He did self-study while doing his PhD, and published a lot of papers with high impacts.

What kind of barriers will he face during the hiring process?

Comment: @Nobody, He never studied any "course". He did self-study while doing his PhD, and published a lot of papers with high impacts.

Comment: @Nobody, I don't know, you tell me.

Comment: @Nobody, I cannot give you hard evidence. However, I know a case at a Spanish university where a person was given a conditional appointment that he has to take some courses and must pass before he starts teaching.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145987/discussion-between-nobody-and-user366312).

Comment: Please see [two comments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194442/should-i-formally-enroll-in-courses-related-to-my-phd#comment532539_194442) I put in the other question. I can move them here if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the this person is applying for academic jobs in statistical mechanics, I would not expect there to be any barriers to hiring - other than the fact that it is not easy for anyone to land good academic positions. That being said, lecturer positions are sometimes open in the sense that they may accept "related" degrees. I have seen many adjunct and lecturer positions like this. All he has to do is convince a hiring committee that he is capable of the job. This is even more true if he is looking outside academia. He is unlikely to be hired for a highly specialized role unrelated to his education, but there are plenty of other ways to leverage a PhD.

It may be a different story if he wants to teach a humanities class, or a class in a discipline totally unrelated to any of his degrees. But, at the same time, in my experience, he may not have a lot of say in what specific classes he teaches if he is hired as more than adjunct faculty i.e. he applied to teach one class in particular. It would also be difficult to convince a university to give him a lab in an unrelated discipline.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the person "just" needs to convince the hiring committee that (s)he is the right person for the job. Other than there is usually no barrier.

Things may sometimes be different with applied topics like medicine, law, or engineering, i.e. areas where you are going to seriously hurt someone if you make a mistake.

Comment: He never studied any "course". He did self-study while doing his PhD, and published a lot of papers with high impacts.

Comment: If the person is hired to teach that course, who cares? Now getting hired is the hard part.